# Regular expression problem

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I search a whole string for a specific match.
It'll contain both characters with int or decimal numbers
eg A12B32.25C-456D-75.E75
I'll know that this will start with A and ends with E 
I think I can use "^" and "$" right?
but i'm bit lost in other parts to check for character and int or decimal.
I'll be glad if you can give the regex and explain it a bit :).

PS. D-75. is not mistyped...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could give us some more info first. Perhaps some better example of those strings you want to match.

Comment: I'll be using this regex in C#.

and for examples
I know that whole string will starts with  character A and a number, B a number, C and a number, D and a number and finally E and a number

So again some example lines would be

A12.2B-45.5C45.D-45E452

A-45.B5.455C-45.D447.1235E985

so i have to match all 5 characters with numbers, may b int or decimals. And point the C45. in first example and A-45. in 2nd example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a free-spacing regex, hoping I'm guessing correctly what you meant:

```
^                   # start of line
A(-?\d+\.?\d*)      # match "A", followed by a number with optional sign and decimal part
B(-?\d+\.?\d*)      # same with "B"
C(-?\d+\.?\d*)      # etc.
D(-?\d+\.?\d*)
E(-?\d+\.?\d*)
$                   # end of line
```

This will capture the numbers into backreferences 1-5. If you tell us how you're planning to use the regex, I can refine my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate this works like a charm
so "?" is for optional and "+" is for one or more and "*" is for zero or more. is it?
sorry i'm not familiar with regex...

Comment: You're welcome. And you got the explanation for the regex quantifiers exactly right :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing literal pattern matching? - you have noticed that you embedded regex metacharacters like a period == . in your pattern.

Depending on what regex engine you are using there may be a 'pattern-only' option.
For example

```
grep -F 'mypattern'  myfile
```

prevents the regex engine from seeing metacharacters in a pattern.

What environment/regex are you using?

Comment: I'll be using this regex in C#.

and for examples
I know that whole string will starts with  character A and a number, B a number, C and a number, D and a number and finally E and a number

So again some example lines would be

A12.2B-45.5C45.D-45E452

A-45.B5.455C-45.D447.1235E985

so i have to match all 5 characters with numbers, may b int or decimals. And point the C45. in first example and A-45. in 2nd example..